# How to add a property to a field type having data

Tags: 8

I have a custom field type. Now I need to add an additional property to it.

I added the new property to `propertyDefinitions()` and `schema()` methods.

What should I do in the update hook? The field type is already in use, and fields have values stored in the database.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up using the following code.

```
function my_module_update_8001() {
  $field_type = 'my_field_type';
  $new_property = 'my_new_property';

  $manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  $field_map = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldMapByFieldType($field_type);
  foreach ($field_map as $entity_type_id => $fields) {
    foreach (array_keys($fields) as $field_name) {
      $field_storage_definition = $manager->getFieldStorageDefinition($field_name, $entity_type_id);
      $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type_id);
      if ($storage instanceof \Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage) {
        $table_mapping = $storage->getTableMapping([
          // We pass only one storage definition to make
          // \Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\DefaultTableMapping::getDedicatedTableNames()
          // return only tables we need.
          $field_name => $field_storage_definition,
        ]);
        $table_names = $table_mapping->getDedicatedTableNames();
        $columns = $table_mapping->getColumnNames($field_name);
        foreach ($table_names as $table_name) {
          $field_schema = $field_storage_definition->getSchema();
          \Drupal::database()
            ->schema()
            ->addField($table_name, $columns[$new_property], $field_schema['columns'][$new_property]);
        }
      }
      $manager->updateFieldStorageDefinition($field_storage_definition);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I could not thank you more! I changed the code slightly to prevent the exceptions

Comment: what would be the opposite? To remove fields?

Answer (score 2):

Based on Alex' answer, I updated the code with non-deprecated code (entity_field.manager). Also fixed two small variable mistakes. This piece of code can be added to .install files for example and will update *all entities* containing the field you'd like to update.

```
$field_type = 'fieldtype_to_be_updated';
$new_property = 'new_property_to_be_added';

$manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
$field_map = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldMapByFieldType($field_type);

foreach ($field_map as $entity_type_id => $fields) {

  foreach (array_keys($fields) as $field_name) {
    $field_storage_definition = $manager->getFieldStorageDefinition($field_name, $entity_type_id);
    $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type_id);

    if ($storage instanceof \Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage) {
      $table_mapping = $storage->getTableMapping([
        $field_name => $field_storage_definition,
      ]);
      $table_names = $table_mapping->getDedicatedTableNames();
      $columns = $table_mapping->getColumnNames($field_name);

      foreach ($table_names as $table_name) {
        $field_schema = $field_storage_definition->getSchema();
        $schema = \Drupal::database()->schema();
        $field_exists = $schema->fieldExists($table_name, $columns[$new_property]);
        $table_exists = $schema->tableExists($table_name);

        if (!$field_exists && $table_exists) {
          $schema->addField($table_name, $columns[$new_property], $field_schema['columns'][$new_property]);
        }
      }
    }
    $manager->updateFieldStorageDefinition($field_storage_definition);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Leksats answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/205748/9449) I added a few lines to prevent some possible exceptions...

```
  $field_type = 'fieldtype';
  $new_property = 'newproperty';

  $manager = \Drupal::entityDefinitionUpdateManager();
  $field_map = \Drupal::entityManager()->getFieldMapByFieldType($field_type);

  foreach ($field_map as $entity_type_id => $fields) {

    foreach (array_keys($fields) as $field_name) {
      $field_storage_definition = $manager->getFieldStorageDefinition($field_name, $entity_type_id);
      $storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type_id);

      if ($storage instanceof \Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage) {
        $table_mapping = $storage->getTableMapping([
          // We pass only one storage definition to make
          // \Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\DefaultTableMapping::getDedicatedTableNames()
          // return only tables we need.
          $field_name => $field_storage_definition,
        ]);
        $table_names = $table_mapping->getDedicatedTableNames();
        $columns = $table_mapping->getColumnNames($field_name);

        foreach ($table_names as $table_name) {
          $field_schema = $field_storage_definition->getSchema();
          $schema = \Drupal::database()->schema();
          $field_exists = $schema->fieldExists($table_name, $columns[$new_property]);
          $table_exists = $schema->tableExists($table_name);

          if (!$fieldExists && $tableExists) {
            $schema->addField($table_name, $columns[$new_property], $field_schema['columns'][$new_property]);
          }
        }
      }
      $manager->updateFieldStorageDefinition($field_storage_definition);
    }
  }
```